# To get the name of the item which was clicked

Tags: android, listview

I have written the code to get the data from database and to bind it to listview now I want to click on perticular item from the listview and to get the name of that item which was clicked.

```
Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllRecords();
        String[] columns = new String[] {
                RecordsDbAdapter.KEY_NAME,
                RecordsDbAdapter.KEY_BIRTHDAY,

        };
        int[] to = new int[] {
                R.id.name,
                R.id.birthdate,
        };
        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, R.layout.row,
                cursor,
                columns,
                to);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"cominggggg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `cursor.moveToPosition(position);` in `listView.setOnItemClickListener` and print the field value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click ListItem Text "
                                + ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Txt))
                                        .getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You can display the toast with selected item name

Comment: you might be inflating the xml file for displaying 'Name' and 'birthdate' in SimpleCursorAdapter() right

Comment: simply add the the ID name which you have given to Name in your row.xml file, in place of "Txt"

Comment: using below code you can store it as String,                                                           String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))                        .getText().toString();

Answer (score 0):

edit ur code like this:--

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            TextView textView = (TextView) view;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),textView.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```